# Autoregular texto justificado en jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

Buen día.

Deseo ajustar un texto en jsPDF sobre un ancho y un alto definido y que se centre o se justifique el texto.

Para justificar encontré esta solución

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','cm','letter');
var text='De la carrera de Técnico Superior Universitario en Procesos Industriales Área Manufactura 
con número de matrícula 182151007 concluyó satisfactoriamente su Servicio Social en un periodo de 6 
meses en  el cual  se cumplieron 480 horas,  conforme a lo dispuesto en el Artículo 55 de la Ley 
Reglamentaria del Artículo 5o Constitucional, relativo al ejercicio de las profesiones.';
doc.text(text, 1, 5, {align: 'justify',lineHeightFactor: 1.5,maxWidth:18});
```

Pero cuando agrego un tipo de letra personalizado se desajusta la justificación:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','cm','letter');
doc.addFileToVFS('arial.ttf','AAEAAAAZAQAABACQRFNJR6jSM0wADRO0AAAdtEdERUYHHgrHAA0xaAAAA1JHUE9TMhEXxQANNLwAAhgUR1NVQrKEa7gAD0zQAACD2EpTVEZtKmkGAA/QqAAAAB5MVFNIqrtZ3QAASNQAABGbT1MvMhRKXYQAAAIYAAAAYFBDTFT9ez5DAA0TfAAAADZWRE1YUJ');
                doc.addFont('arial.ttf', 'arial', 'normal');
                doc.setFont('arial');
                doc.setFontSize(22);
var text='De la carrera de Técnico Superior Universitario en Procesos Industriales Área Manufactura con número de matrícula 182151007 concluyó satisfactoriamente su Servicio Social en un periodo de 6 meses en  el cual  se cumplieron 480 horas,  conforme a lo dispuesto en el Artículo 55 de la Ley Reglamentaria del Artículo 5o Constitucional, relativo al ejercicio de las profesiones.';
doc.text(text, 1, 5, {align: 'justify',lineHeightFactor: 1.5,maxWidth:18});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para ell ancho definido aún no he encontrado algo ¿me podrían ayudar por favor?
Gracias!